# Application.Goto How to achieve immediate results?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Application.Goto in a subroutine, but Excel waits after the subroutine is finished before it scrolls to the cell.
This is the line:

`Application.Goto Reference:=S.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True`

After this line there's a Userform that's showing with multiple choices. When the Userform is open, you can't scroll. I want the sheet to scroll to cell A1 and then open the Userform. How can I make the scrolling instant? I've tried to add `DoEvents` and `Application.Wait(Now + Timeserial(0, 0, 1))` after the line but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/modeless.htm

Comment: Wait it wasn't optimal. I want the code to stop after the UserForm is shown and wait for input, before resuming. Now it just run through the whole subroutine til the end. Is it possible to halt the code just like before I added vbModeless?